# GTK C - `GtkStock’ & `GTK_CAN_FOCUS` is deprecated

Tags: c, gtk

After few problems with GTK+ in C I thought that I finally managed to solve my biggest problem with checkbox. Unfortunately no ;/

After using g_signal_connect:

```
g_signal_connect (ur, "toggled",G_CALLBACK(user_read_only), (gpointer *)filename);
```

Where function user_read_only is this:

```
void user_read_only(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer *filename)
{
   if (gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(widget))){
       int stat;
       stat = chmod(data, S_IRUSR);
       printf("Added Read attribute to user in file: %s\n", (char *)filename);
   } else {
      printf("No Read attribute to user in file: %s\n", (char *)filename);
   }
}
```

I compile by using:

```
gcc -o s8 s8.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`
```

I get the following warning:

```
    s8.c: In function ‘main’: 
    s8.c:49:1: warning: ‘GtkStock’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations] dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Open File",NULL,GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,GTK_STOCK_CANCEL,GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,GTK‌​_STOCK_OPEN,GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,NULL); 
    ^ 
    s8.c:49:1: warning: ‘GtkStock’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations] 
    s8.c:78:29: error: ‘GTK_CAN_FOCUS’ undeclared (first use in this function) 

    GTK_WIDGET_UNSET_FLAGS(ur, GTK_CAN_FOCUS);
```

I'm trying to find information on how I'm supposed to go about this. The only things that come up online with this warning is trying use gtk+ 3.0

Is there a way to go about this? I need dialog box to let user select file, which user can set chmods.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
gtk_widget_set_can_focus(ur)
```

Instead of

```
GTK_WIDGET_UNSET_FLAGS(ur, GTK_CAN_FOCUS);
```

[documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-can-focus)

Answer (score 1):

Buttons like GTK_STOCK_OK and GTK_STOCK_CANCEL can be translated to "_Ok" and "_Cancel" as noted in documentation.

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Stock-Items.html#GTK-STOCK-CANCEL:CAPS